# How to stop cookie prompt while using Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell

Tags: cookies, powershell-5.0

I have a script that uses Invoke-WebRequest.  It has worked fine until yesterday when it pauses for a prompt to accept cookies in a window button.

`$webpage = Invoke-WebRequest -SessionVariable session "https://www.decades.com/schedule"`

[image]

I have since:

- Added `-SessionVariable session` to the request - no change
- Checked IE security level - looked usual

[image]

- IE Privacy Settings were/are set to `Accept`

[image]

- I could not reproduce the message by manually placing the
  command line in a manual PowerShell session

I, to my knowledge:

- Do not have Internet Explorer installed (not in Apps list)
- Have not made any settings changes to any Internet Explorer or Edge

Thanks

Windows 10 Pro; PowerShell v5.1

Comment: when you say "I could not reproduce the message by manually placing the command line in a manual PowerShell session" are you trying to say that running the command in PS interactively works fine, but when you run it from a script or job it fails and you get the allow cookies popup? if so, please describe how you are running the script.

Comment: @ Frank. Yes.  Normally the script is running; the website request is executed at a particular time/event - it waits for a file to be created.  The "manually" part was my attempt to recreate the message in a separate PS session, manually, while troubleshooting.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the environment of the user running the task when it is automated. how are you automating the task?

Comment: @ Frank. The script is run by a task; the web request exists in a sub-script file, which is called by `. C:\Users...scrape_rename.ps1`.  What was surprising is that it has worked for months without this popup.  I *may* have made some change in Edge, but I cannot clearly remember (and I think I was only fussing with bookmarks).  I do not get any messages like this while running Edge in normal use.  I thought image #3 (above) would be the setting, but it appears no to be.  I have also re-booted (Restart) several times.

Comment: what user does the task run on? does anyone ever log in interactively using that account? is it possible that most of the time there is a session for that user in the background, and now perhaps due to reboot, that is not the case? or is it possible that another system prereq is not met, like a completed network connection? some tasks require you to check a box to only run the task when the network is up if they run at startup

Comment: The user is a Local Account Administrator account. I use Android FE Explorer to log into it, and I use VLC from a Fire TV to log in to the computer; no anomalies. No other person logs in to the computer.  There is never another PS session running in the background, and I keep high familiarity this via Task Manager - very positive of this.  I'm not sure about network connections, but all seems as previously was.  It is a very dedicated computer.  Is it possible Edge/Windows installed an update and changed a setting? Other updates have been seamless. Parent script `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `-disablekeepalive` .  This website I invoke is a local weather conditions station, and it appears sophisticated with additional timely updating.  So far, my per-chance attempt has worked, and I can capture the conditions of its moment.

I'm not sure why it suddenly changed, as everything appears unchanged from previous functionality, but it did.